# Extjs5 : ComboBox not showing the selected value

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox

I created a `comboBox` and when I select a value, no value will be displayed.

```
 Ext.create("Ext.form.field.ComboBox", {
        name: el.name,
        fieldLabel: el.labelId,
        hidden: !(el.visible),
        displayField:"value",
        valueField:"value",
        flex: 1,
        store:Ext.create("Ext.data.Store",{
               fields: ['key', 'value'],
               data: [
                        { key: "10",value: "etap 0"},
                        { key: "200",value: "etape 1"},
                        { key: "300", value: "etape 3"}
               ]
        }),
        regex: el.parameterType.regex,
        regexText: el.regExErrMsg,
        allowBlank: !el.mandatory,
        blankText: el.requiredErrMsg
    })
```

**EDIT**

Here is exactly the method that return combo:

```
 drawField: function (el) {
    var me = this;
    var uiField = Ext.create(me.componentType, {
        name: el.name,
        fieldLabel: el.labelId,
        hidden: !(el.visible),
        flex: 1,
        regex: el.parameterType.regex,
        regexText: el.regExErrMsg,
        allowBlank: !el.mandatory,
        blankText: el.requiredErrMsg
    });
    if (el.parameterType.isCombo) {
        uiField.displayField = 'value';
        uiField.valueField = 'key';
        uiField.editable = false;
        uiField.store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['key', 'value'],
            data: el.parameterType.values
        });
    }
    return uiField;
}
```

and `el` parameter is a JavaScript object like that:

```
{
    name: "",
    labelId: "Champ :",
    parameterType: {
        regEx: "^.*$",
        errID: "115",
        isCombo: true,
        values:[
            {key: "10", value: "etap 0"},
            {key: "200",value: "etape 1"},
            {key: "300",value: "etape 3"},
        ],
        selectedValue: "etap 0"
    },
    mandatory: false,
    visible: true,
    defaultValue: "",
    elementType: "LIST_BOX",
    regExErrMsg: "Valeur invalide.",
    requiredErrMsg: ""
}
```

and `me.componentType` at runtime is `Ext.form.field.ComboBox`

Comment: How are you selecting the value?

Comment: I selected the value manually

Comment: How are you selecting the value manually?

Comment: Any errors in web console? BTW there is a missing comma after `store:` definition

Comment: The combo is rendred in the navigator, and I select a value from the list displayed. After selection, the value is not shown in the combo
No error in the javascript Console

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the value is displayed in the dropdown, but not in the (editable) form field?

Comment: Yes that's exactelly the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This fiddle works fine for me, I removed the references to el as it shown undefined for me and also changed Ext.data.store to Ext.data.Store

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/jj6

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function() {
        Ext.create("Ext.form.field.ComboBox", {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            displayField: "value",
            valueField: "value",
            flex: 1,
            store: Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
                fields: ['key', 'value'],
                data: [{
                    key: "10",
                    value: "etap 0"
                }, {
                    key: "200",
                    value: "etape 1"
                }, {
                    key: "300",
                    value: "etape 3"
                }]
            })
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not the same case for me :(

Comment: could you create a fiddle with your code so that we can debug it, are you getting console errors?

Answer (score 0):

valueField:"value" is wrong, you should specify valueField:"key" in order for ComboBox to work properly

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think that this is the reason for the problem. I try it but the problem persist

Comment: it is check alsmost the same piece of code as yours here http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-valueField. ComboBox should store values using ID from data store not captions of items